# Trying to share Gulp project with a friend

Tags: regex, gulp, array-unique, gulp-watch, semantic-versioning

I have made a gulp project and I am trying to share it with a friend. 
Its a simple css grid with gulp tasks integrated.

You can download the package here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/od1dsh75tegbq24/projectfolder.zip?dl=1

When you unzip the package and make sure you have node.js, ruby and gulp.js installed and try to run the gulpfile, it throws the following error:

```
Cannot find module "semver-regex"
```

After I install that (npm install --save semver-regex)
It throws the same kind of error with:

```
Cannot find module "array-uniq"
```

After I install that, the build proces works, but liveReload and watch tasks don't...

Is there a way to share Gulpfiles without all the hassle? I just want it to be downloaded and used :)

Package.json is in the root:

```html
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp-minify-css": "^0.3.10",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.4.1",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.0.1",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^1.0.1",
    "imagemin-pngcrush": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-html-replace": "^1.3.0",
    "gulp-connect": "^2.0.6",
    "gulp-open": "^0.2.8",
    "run-sequence": "^1.0.0",
    "streamqueue": "^0.1.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: We're not downloading your 47Mb project... And all data relevant to the question should be in the question. That said, the idea is to list your dependencies in `package.json`, and just run `npm install` to install the lot.

Comment: I understand. But the dependencies are listed. Still getting errors...

Comment: If `semver-regex` and `array-uniq` are listed, you did `npm install` (not individual `npm install semver-regex` etc), and still getting errors, then something is wrong; inspect the output of `npm install`.